# Double serialization customization

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public double SomeValue {get;set;}
}
```

I need to serialize it by `XmlSerializer` but I need to multiply the value by 10 during serialization and divide it by 10 during deserialization. Is there any way to implement this custom logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a bit hacky, but involves not serialising your main property, but providing a dummy property for the purposes of serialization that gets/sets the backing field for your main propery appropriately.

```
public class SomeClass 
{ 
   private double _someValue;

   [XmlIgnore()]
   public double SomeValue {
     get { return _someValue; }
     set {_someValue = value;}
   } 

   [XmlElement("SomeValue")]
   public double SomeValueSerialised
   {
      get { return _someValue * 10; }
      set { _someValue = value/10; }
   }
}
```

---

Edit: Would note, the implementation of IXmlSerializable is probably a cleaner way to do this, but it really depends on the number of fields on your class and how lazy you're feeling...

Comment: You might want to add `[XmlElement("SomeValue")]` so the xml looks like the original

Comment: @Marc Gravell - didn't know you could do that.  Answer amended with your suggestion.

Comment: And may be it is a good idea to add EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never) to SoveValueSerialized property

Comment: @Idsa actually, the one that is usually more useful (perhaps in combination) is `[Browsable(false)]`, which stops it appearing in things like `PropertyGrid` and `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement yourself [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx):

```
public class SomeClass:IXmlSerializable
{
   public double SomeValue {get;set;}
 // implement here below read write as needed
 // Xml Serialization Infrastructure

public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
{
    ...
}

public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
{
    ...
}

public XmlSchema GetSchema()
{
    return(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can control the serialization by implementing IXmlSerializable interface.
Try this out..

```
public class SomeClass: IXmlSerializable
{
   private double someValue;
   public double SomeValue 
   {
      get{ return someValue;}
      set{ someValue = value;}
   }
   public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
   {
      writer.WriteString(someValue * 10);
   }

   public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
   {
      someValue = Convert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString()) / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not apply to `XmlSerializer`